# how to programmatically change post tags

Tags: posts, tags

Is there a php function which can add/remove tags of posts? If not how would I do this?

I am looking for something like this:

```
add_tag($post_id, 'tag-name');
remove_tag($post_id, 'tag-name');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key function you're looking for here is `wp_set_post_tags()`.

To add the tag 'awesome' to post 98,

```
wp_set_post_tags( 98, array( 'awesome' ), true );
```

Note that the `true` parameter means that this tag will be added to the existing post tags. If you omit this value, it defaults to `false`, and the existing post tags will be overwritten with the new ones being passed.

To delete a tag, first pull up a list of the existing post tags using https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( 98 );
```

Then assemble a list of the tags you want to keep (which will exclude the one you're "deleting"), and replace the existing post tags with the new list:

```
$tags_to_delete = array( 'radical', 'bodacious' );
$tags_to_keep = array();
foreach ( $tags as $t ) {
    if ( !in_array( $t->name, $tags_to_delete ) ) {
        $tags_to_keep[] = $t->name;
    }
}

wp_set_post_tags( 98, $tags_to_keep, false );
```

Comment: wow... i have looked for this for a long while... didnt knew about wp_ wp_set_post_tags - the only missing part in a front end article edit form :) - thanks a bunch